# Google spreadsheet month name (MMMM) without declension

Tags: date, google-sheets, date-formatting

I want to display formatted month name in the basic form (nominative) as a label. In Czech language (and several next Slavic languages) we use [declension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Czech_declension). So if I use `=TEXT(NOW();"MMMM")` the cell shows month name in genetive instead of nominative (i.e. *srpna* instead of [*srpen*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/srpen#Declension)).

**Q:** How to format the date in the nominative? The acceptable solution will offer some native way how to solve it but **not**:

- manipulating with strings (month names are too complex)
- having some another list with month names
- calling own formula (Google script)

Maybe there is no native way how to solve this and it will be implemented in the future, so Google Script seems to be the easiest hotfix for now. And because I'm expecting many answers with the script, I'm putting the one here but this question is not about the javascript/google-script.

```js
function monthName(date) {
  var months = ["Leden","Únor","Březen","Duben","Květen", "Červen","Červenec","Srpen","Září","Říjen","Listopad","Prosinec"];
  return months[date.getMonth()];
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Rubén I did a minor edit and added the (obvious) question.

Comment: Javascript/Google-Script tags has been removed because this question is NOT about that way of solution.